# What is proper way to get multiple fields from da.SearchCursor?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I just buried a couple of hours not realizing that I can't do this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fp_in, ['OBJECTID', 'name']) as cursor:
  objectid = [row[0] for row in cursor]
  name = [row2[1] for row2 in cursor]
  # now do some stuff with those two lists
```

the `objectid` variable comes out as a list with numbers from the feature, as it should.  However the name field comes up `[]` (empty).  Apparently I don't know with blocks or list comprehensions because it seems I destroyed the cursor object after first use?  I am confused.  `name` IS a field and it exists.  I solved this by doing the ugly initiate a blank list and append:

```
objectid = []
name = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fp_in, ['OBJECTID', 'name']) as cursor:
  for row in cursor
    objectid.append(row[0])
    name.append(row[1])
```

But there has to be a prettier way right?

Comment: Parallel arrays are an odd goal when you could build a dictionary. This feels like a XY Problem. What do you intend to do with the data?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: my goal is to create a function taking two args: a list of fields i.e. ['OBJECTID', 'name', 'date']` and  a nested list of target vals in each field, i.e. name = ['Lebron', 'Sam Perkins'’].  In general fields = [field1, field2…fieldN] and vals = [[f1_vals], [f2_vals]…[fN_vals]].  Then create a df with only rows containing vals present from each field.  For example, `df = df[df.field1.isin(field1_vals)]`.  Ultimately trying to avoid stringing arcpy functions and saving features by compiling an  idx/OBJECTID list for selecting features from feature layer when all is done. Does that make sense?

Comment: hmmm, I'm a bit ignorant on a basic programming concept it seems Vince.  I'll Google it, but what is an XY problem?  I see what you are saying though.  A dictionary, or directly building a data structure like a Pandas DataFrame is less clunky than saving multiple lists?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the python docs:

> `zip()` in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list:

So you could do:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fp_in, ['OBJECTID', 'name']) as cursor:
  rows = [row for row in cursor]    # I don't know if zip() works with cursor (can't test)
  objectid, name = list(zip(*rows)) # If it does work, use objectid, name = list(zip(*cursor))
  # now do some stuff with those two lists
```

Comment: Your solution basically works, but it returns tuples, while it seems that lists are preferred by asking person . Plus, if it is arcmap 10.x then Python  2.x is used, which means we don't have to convert zip result to list, as it is list already. Of course Vince's comment is still valid, I don't  understand the essence of the question as well...

Comment: A barrage of responses to comments on my end.  Thanks for the help everyone!  The essence of the question is basically two things: 1) my first comment in response to Vince - how to unpack a cursor object preferably into a dataframe.  Getting a list was more of  an intermediate step.  2)  Generally I didn't realize the cursor object was only accessible once in my first code block: `objectid = [row[0] for row in cursor]
  name = [row2[1] for row2 in cursor]` as `objectid` yields a populated list but `name = []`.  And you are right Syzm, zip did yield tuples which I had to `list(tuple)`finally.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I settled on.  It's a function that returns a dataframe with all rows from my desired fields.

```
def list_unique_fields(fp_feat, field):
    import arcpy
    import pandas as pd

    # turn FIELD into list if not a list
    if isinstance(field, list):
        pass
    else:
        field = [field]
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fp_feat, field) as cursor:
        rows = [row for row in cursor]
        vals = zip(*rows)
        for idx, field in enumerate(field):
            # initiate dictionary for first field
            if 'dict' not in locals():
                dict = {field : vals[idx]}
            else:
                dict[field] = vals[idx]
        df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    return(df)
```

Use the function as follows:

```
fp = 'C:/Users/Zach/GIS/gauge_stations'
field = ['OBJECTID', 'gauge_type']
df = list_unique_fields(fp, field)
```

...And a dataframe (df) shall be returned